# What version of .net will MVC 2 require?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Will MVC 2 run on .net framework version 4.0 or 3.5 sp1?  Has Microsoft even made an announcement yet as to what the requirements are?

Also, Will MVC 2 be an installation separate from .net 4.0 or will it be installed with 4.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx), ASP.NET MVC 2 is designed to work with both VS 2008 / .NET 3.5, as well as with VS 2010 / .NET 4.

for the mvc 2 installation question

> ASP.NET MVC 2 is a built-in component
>   of VS 2010 / .NET 4 – which means you
>   will not have to download or install
>   anything to get it once you install
>   any version of Visual Studio 2010. 
>   The current public VS 2010 Beta 2
>   release includes the ASP.NET MVC 2
>   Preview 2 release.  The upcoming VS
>   2010 Release Candidate that will be
>   available for download next month will
>   have a more recent ASP.NET MVC 2 RC
>   built-in.

Comment: To be slightly more correct: ASP.NET MVC 2 is included in VS2010, but it is *not* included in .NET 4. That is, if you have a clean Windows machine and install .NET 4, you will not have ASP.NET MVC 2. You can then go download ASP.NET MVC 2 and it'll work on both .NET 3.5/4 and VS2008/VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, certainly helps clear things up!

Answer (score 2):

It will run on .NET 3.5 SP1 and higher

Answer (score 1):

MVC 2 will be fine with either.  The *next* version of MVC will require 4.0 or later, but this new "2" is fine either way.

The final Visual Studio 2010 will have MVC 2 included.  For now the MVC 2 release candidate is a download, available **[here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b537c55-0948-4e6a-bf8c-aa1a78878da0&displaylang=en)**.

Comment: Got any information on the _next_ version?  Searching for this stuff is hard because there is so much out there on mvc and asp.net that it all gets lost in the ether

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2 has just barely been released as RC not even a month ago - there's very little you'll find on the next version seeing how this one is not even out.

Comment: No, not much information on MVC 3.  I just heard this verbally from one of the designers in an interview, that it will more target .NET 4.  (although Microsoft sometimes skips numbers.  Maybe it will be MVC . . . 2012!)

Comment: Ah OK, I was starting to think I was completely behind the curve.  I've always been aware of MVC 2 and that they just went into RC.  Since you mentioned the _next_ one, I thought it was right around the corner heh

Comment: The current plan for ASP.NET MVC 3 is that it will required .NET 4, but nothing public is announced.

Comment: Here we go, from Phil Haack's website:  " . . . ASP.NET MVC 3 will be compiled against ASP.NET 4 only (no support for ASP.NET 3.5 planned) . . ."  Here's the page:  http://goo.gl/a1Ya I've heard this several times from he and others, but this is **not official**.  And yes, this is still a ways off, even with how relatively quickly MVC iterations are released

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b537c55-0948-4e6a-bf8c-aa1a78878da0&displaylang=en

System **Requirements**

Supported Operating Systems: Windows 7; Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista

**.NET 3.5 SP1**. Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2008 SP1 are required to use certain parts of this feature.